# Show that there are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to describe $n$ as a sum with $k$ positive, ordered parts

Tags: binomial-coefficients

> Show that there are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to describe $n$ as a sum of $k$ positive, ordered parts.

I know that there are $n-k+1$ options for the first part of the sum. And the first choice affects the choice for the snd part and so on. I have also tried a proof by induction, assuming that there are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to describe $n$ as a $k$-part sum, we pick one possibility and add 1 to one of the parts and we get $n+1$  That means there would be $k\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to describe $n+1$ but there are doubles such that $(m_1,\dots,m_k)\ne(m'_1,\dots,m'_k)$ but $(m_1,\dots,m_i+1,\dots,m_k) = (m'_1,\dots,m'_j + 1,\dots,m'_k)$ with $i\ne j$ and $m_1 + \dots+ m_k = n = m'_1 +\dots+ m'_k$ and $m'_1 +\dots+ m'_j + 1 +\dots+ m'_k  = m_1 +\dots + m_i + 1 +\dots+ m_k = n + 1$.

It would be good if we could show somehow that there are $\binom nk$ ways to describe $n+1$.

These are my ideas maybe I am completely wrong with my approaches if so please tell me, any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: For clarity, by `describe $n$ as a sum with $k$ parts', do you mean writing $n$ as a sum of $k$ strictly positive integers?

Comment: Yes the question is edited correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are, indeed, completely missing a direct solution. Picture $n$ stars and $k-1$ bars which go into the $n-1$ gaps between the stars, at most one bar per gap. Then the $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways to put the bars in the gaps are in bijection with the number of ways to describe $n$ as a sum in $k$ (ordered, positive) parts; I leave it to you to show this bijection.

Comment: In case anyone's unfamiliar with this general technique (which is worth learning), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)